# Chrome version 56 change event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I have a problem with the latest version of Chrome.

We have an autocomplete field. When a user types then a list shows up as they type and they have to select one. They select a value and when they click away the field is firing a change event. From what I read at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change that is supposed to happen. But it doesnt happen in IE and didnt happen in versions of Chrome prior to 56.

So can anyone tell me if it is working correctly in version 56? Is it a bug in previous versions and IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We too have the same issue with latest chrome update. What we did to fix was to declare  two variables and checked them in the onChange event.

```
var itemSelected = false;
  var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    function fieldName_ItemSelected(source, eventArgs) {
     //Code to get selected value goes here
      itemSelected  = true;
    }
```

Then in the onChange Event,added condition to check for chrome and empty the value accordingly.

```
function fieldNameChanged(obj) {
   if (isChrome) {
                if (itemSelected == false) {   
                    $('#<%= hdnField.ClientID %>').val('');
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#<%= hdnField.ClientID %>').val('');
            }
}
```

Hope this helps.